# How to provide space between input type text and input button in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my image http://s7.postimg.org/l0ib3cbez/Untitled_2.png

Here there is no space between input type text and input button.

If i provide, margin-top, it doesn't working.

Html:

```
<form action="//holycrap.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=86019d1f16af8d19cbc0de4ed&amp;id=ae25f1fcdc" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <h3>Email Address </h3>
</div>

    <div class="frm-main">
        <div class="frmheader">
            <div class="bodyText"><img src="{{ 'email-sign-up-image-revised.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">          
            <input class="text" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL"  id="mce-EMAIL">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="sidebar-button">  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

css:

```
.frm-main input.text {
height: 29px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-color: #D9D9D9;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
width: 219px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.frm-main, input[type="submit"]{
border: medium none;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #9F2214;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: none;
width:162px;
line-height: 1px;
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: try padding at your button

Comment: yes, i tried padding too, it doesn't work.. thanks

Comment: @selva padding doesnt work? , where did u put the padding?

Comment: @selva put the padding-bottom for your .frm-main input.text

Comment: here .. .frm-main, input[type="button"] {
    padding-top:10px;
    }

Comment: oh man. You have padding, but you set red color to your container, so you cant see this padding. Remove .frm-main selector from your css code

Comment: @MohitBhasi: padding bottom also didn't work

Comment: I need distance between these two inputs @degr, for that what can i do,, can you please explain?

Comment: just add this one
input{
border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: added, but nothing change @degr

Comment: Can you please share a working link of your work, where the same issue exist. I think this might be because of some other elements.

Comment: I wrote style to you.

Comment: yes,, but it didn't take this style, it took default input styles,, @degr

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="submit"]{
    margin-top:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

I have edited my answer, now it's working; 
I have copied your original css line as it was, but the comma gave to the .frm-main class the same values so they were merging somehow.

Comment: not working,, text only placed at margin-top:10px, and i need to add styles for particular this .frm-main, input[type="submit"]

Answer (score 0):

```
.frm-main{
background-color: white !important;
}
input{
min-height: 20px;
}
.frm-main input.text {
height: 29px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-color: #D9D9D9;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
width: 219px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.frm-main, input[type="submit"]{
border: medium none;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #9F2214;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: none;
width:162px;
line-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: okay @degr, but button styles are didn't change.. i need like this styles for button http://s27.postimg.org/3ru7uhh9f/Untitled_2.png.. now it look like this http://s22.postimg.org/s7efuuevl/Untitled_2.png

Comment: It didn't take your this styles .frm-main, input[type="submit"]{..}

Comment: sorry, i can't able to follow that video.. thanks @degr

Comment: I can advice to you find some lessons about chrome dev tools for html-css-javascript debug.

Comment: already i have default styles for input button and text. so when i try to change styles for my .frm-main input button. it didn`t take...

Comment: and if i use button instead of input type button. it will work fine.but i need styles in input type only..